# react-native-navigation how to detect current screen inside `shouldComponentUpdate`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm using react-native-navigation and using redux for state management. when I go to screenA to screenB with "push" method and the screenA won't unmount. this will cause unwanted rerenders and previously in react-navigation I used shouldComponentUpdate to match component with the currently visible screen to stop re-render.

Is there a way to do this in react-native-navigation?

Answer (score 2):

When you set a navigator events handler (using `addOnNavigatorEvent`) you can track screen lifecycle events and get notified when a screen disappears or appears.

Alternatively you can check if the screen is currently visible using `await this.props.navigator.screenIsCurrentlyVisible()`, though i'm not sure what are the implications of doing this in `shouldComponentUpdate` since it performs a native call which needs to cross the bridge and might add unnecessary delays.

You can see more about screen visibility [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=screen-visibility).